# Continue after exception

Tags: python, wmi

Help me figure out how the script will keep on running when WMI can't connect to host and go to next computer in list. Should I use continue after except?

```
import wmi
MachineList = ["Computer1","Computer2","Computer3"]
try:
    for machines in MachineList:
        c = wmi.WMI(machines) # <---- Go to next in the for loop when connection fail???
        for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
            print os.Caption
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Don't use bare `except`. Declare the type you're trying to catch.

Answer (score 4):

```
import wmi
MachineList = ["Computer1","Computer2","Computer3"]
for machines in MachineList:
    try:
        c = wmi.WMI(machines) # <---- Go to next in the for loop when connection fail???
        for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
            print os.Caption
    except Exception: #Intended Exception should be mentioned here
        print "Cannot Connect to {}".format(machines)
```

Generally speaking unless you are using exception for control flow, it should be caught as soon as plausible to prevent mixing with other exceptions. Also you should be specific what exception you want to catch rather than catching something generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
for machine in MachineList:
    try:
        c = wmi.WMI(machine)
        for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
            print os.caption
    except Exception:
        print "Failed on machine %s" % machine
```